# Lightning: Can a channel partner betray with an arbitrary balance?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, ln-penalty-transaction

I know, that I can settle old balances in a closing transaction. But can I also settle arbitrary "fantasy" balances in a force close when my channel partner is long dead. By example by modifying the transaction DB of my lnd node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can pick the revoked state (or "old balance" in your terminology) that is most beneficial to you i.e. the highest old balance that you previously had in the channel and broadcast that one if you are seeking to cheat your counterparty. It may be that one of the previously revoked states is one where you own effectively all the balance in the channel (e.g. if you single funded the channel in the first place). But you can't create a state that didn't previously exist where you own all the Bitcoin in the channel without getting a signature from the counterparty in the channel. If the counterparty in the channel broadcasts a revoked state then you can under the current LN penalty mechanism seize all the funds in the channel with a justice transaction but again it requires a previous action from the counterparty.

Comment: @RenePickhardt: Circular rebalances would still require the channel counterparty to agree (and sign for) every change in state in the channel right?

Comment: Sry misread the question. Deleted my comment!